# Prove that for all x, y ∈ Z if 7 divides 8x + 23y, then 7 divides x + 2y.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics, real-numbers, formal-proofs

Can someone help me solve this question?

Prove that for all x, y ∈ Z if 7 divides 8x + 23y, then 7 divides x + 2y.

I know it's about division algorithm. I just started practicing but not being able to solve.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint:  $8=7+1$ and $23=7\times 3+2$.

Answer (score 1):

We know that:
$$8x+23y\equiv 0\mod 7$$
We can write $8$ as $7+1$ and $23$ as $7\cdot3+2$, substituibg, we have:
$$7x+x+7\cdot3y+y\equiv 0\mod 7$$
And so, by the proprieties of modular arithmetic, we have:
$$x+2y\equiv 0\mod 7$$
which implies that $x+2y$ is a multiple of $7$.

Comment: @Windsormath: if this answer has been useful, maybe a $+1$ or a favourite answer?

Answer (score 1):

Observe that If $\; a\; |\; b \;$ and $ \;a \;| \;c\;  $ then

$$ a\; | \;(b-c)$$

We know that
$$ 7 \;|\; 21 y$$ and
$$7\; | \;7x$$

so, if $ \; 7 \;|\; 8x + 23y \; $ 
then

$$7 \;|\; (8x+23y)  - 7x - 21y$$